# Convert windows browser support my JQuery code to iPhone Safari support Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, safari

My following code is working fine in windows desktop browser but this code not working in iPhone Safari browser.

Code:

```
$(document).on("keydown", ".iselectinput", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8 && $(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).prev().find("li.ioption:last").remove();
    }
});

$(document).on('click', ".iselect .dropdown-menu a", function() {
    var loc1 = $(this).parent().prev().prev();
    var loc2 = $(this);
    var loc3 = loc1.find("li.ioption");
    var isInList2 = !!$(loc3).filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == loc2.text();
    }).length;
    if (!isInList2) {
        loc1.append('<li class="ioption">' + $(this).text() + '<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>');
        loc2.remove();
    }
});
```

How to convert this code to iPhone safari browser support code. I think jQuery `prev()` and `.filter` not working in iPhone safari browser.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code or a fiddle please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ugdhyetb/ I can't make that ajax response.